# Dax measure to remove the date filter and provide the all resultant column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a scenario where I have a date filter on the page, for one of my widget, I want all the column data without considering d filter.

I tried using All(C1), but when I drag the dax to report, gives me error , expecting single value but getting multiple[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your current measure for which you are getting error?

Comment: I have added the scenario pic. DDABugcount(DAX measure where i have used allexcept filter to ignore the date filter) is 114 in total, but because of the date filter applied only 91 of them are getting fetched. I want ometing same to be done while fetching the bug rows too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on your slicer (Month in your picture), then go to `Format > Edit Interaction`and then click on `None`(grey circle)

[image]

on your table. This way the table ignores the filter which comes form the specific slicer. With the grey circle you can basically turn off/on the interaction (ignore slicer or not).